# How to differentiate between load and short circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am working on a project. The goal is to differentiate between short circuit and load. I am trying to use differential amplifier. At load there are 2 to 3 millivolts. I need to compare them with zero volt and get a reasonable volt at output of this opamp.

How do I differentiate between a load and short circuit on the output of a differential amplifier?

Comment: A differential amp is probably the correct way to do this, but you'll have to be careful about offset, layout and noise to accurately distinguish a couple of mV from a short.  If the load is resistive you could try using a current sense amplifier.  It's also important to know how quickly you need to react to a short.

Comment: What are you protecting? and how much current can the voltage-divider use to set the threshold? how fast MUST the short-circuit (200% of nominal?) be detected? Using 100Kohmresistors in a 1MHz bandwidth circuit, you will have 40 microvolt RMS, or 250 microvolt PeakPeak 6 sigma (1 ppm) noise.

Comment: @john D .for the problem i mentioned,how to use current sense amplifier you mentioned?

Comment: @Muhammad take a look at products like these: http://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/current-sense/analog-output/products.html .  There is lots of application information in the datasheets.

Answer (score 1):

For this application I would recommend a comparator (since all you care about is whether or not your millivolt threshold is exceeded and not the information in the signal itself).

[image: Inverting comparator configuration]

Use the R1/R2 divider to set your reference voltage to a few millivolts.  You will want to use high-grade components depending on the level of accuracy you are after.  Alternatively you can change the divider out for a potentiometer which would allow you to set arbitrary thresholds.

In the inverting configuration, once the Vin is below Vref the output will go high indicating a "short".

Comment: It will be very difficult to get a single stage comparator to work when the threshold voltage is so small.  On a 3.3V regulated supply you're looking for a threshold that is 500 ppm of the supply, or 0.05% of reference.  You probably need a differential amplifier stage first.

Comment: @ROB, Thankyou very much.
input signal is AC.Secondly there are 2.5 millivolts across load.So if voltage across load are below 2.5millivolts,means there is short circuit.
How can i proceed?
Can i drive relay from ouptu of above meniode topolgy advised by you?

Comment: @scorpdaddy A pre-amp may be unecessary depending on the exact threshold desired and accuracy.  The AD790 for example has an offset of 0.25mV and hysteresis of 0.5mV.

Comment: @user219130 If it's an AC signal then you can't use the above circuit as it is because the output will oscillate according to the frequency.  A simple solution would be to flip the inputs to form a non-inverting configuration but this would mean that the output during normal operation is a square wave and the output during a "short" is zero.  It really depends on what kind of circuitry you are using to monitor the output.

Comment: @Rob..can you please send me circuit for understanding ?

Comment: @Rob.  Good points about the AD790 voltage errors.  However that is not the problem.  The much bigger problem is the accuracy of the resistors that set the threshold.  Good resistors have 1% error.  That would be 20x the accuracy needed to set a threshold voltage of 0.05% of reference.

Comment: @Muhammad What is the voltage range you are working with?  An easier method may be to use a shunt resistor in series with the load and measure the voltage across it instead.  Do you know how much current your load would draw normally?

Comment: @Muhammad If that's the case then where are you measuring the few millivolts from?  Can you provide more details of the circuit and the load?

Comment: @Muhammad I am having trouble visualising your circuit.  A circuit break should remove all power from the circuit i.e. the load shouldn't still have current flowing through it and a neon bulb in series.  Both active and neutral lines should pass through the breaker and both be severed from the load when tripped.  Any indicator light will be sourcing power from the lines feeding into the breaker.  What are you using to measure the load with once the circuit breaks?

Comment: @Muhammad Why is the circuit breaker tripping when there is still a load present?  Is the load drawing more current then the breaker is rated for?  Unless the breaker is faulty, it is likely tripping for a reason.  As I said before, there SHOULD NOT be any current flowing through the load once the breaker trips.

Comment: @Muhammad Sounds like a strange and possibly dangerous setup, but if that is the case then there are 3 conditions:
1) Regular current flow through the breaker and load in series
2) Current flow through the neon bulb and a short circuit
3) Current flow through the neon bulb and the load
In order to distinguish between the 2nd and 3rd scenarios, you need to measure the current moving through the circuit.  In scenario 2, the current will ONLY be limited by the internal resistance of the bulb.  If you can measure this then you have your reference current for a 'true' short circuit.